# Get the next time of starting a Celery periodic task

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I have several Celery periodic tasks which were defined via Django Celery admin page. How can I get information using Python about when tasks will be executed in the next time?

Comment: What about querying those tables where that information is stored?

Comment: DB stores information about the last executing time and crontab/interval for the task. I want to find a built-in method to solve a task.

Comment: I think there is no such method. Or let me know if you find something similar built in :)

Answer (score 0):

get my_task from db and then:

```
last_run_at = my_task.last_run_at
interval_every = my_task.interval.every
next_run_at = last_run_at + datetime.timedelta(0, interval_every)
```

Comment: last_run_at doesn't seem to be consistently accurate for my interval-based periodic task

Comment: What if last_run_at is empty, which is the case when the task has never been run?